# Computing Two Same Values in Two Data Frame Gives Different Results in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to multiply the each value of a column with the overall value of the column for some reason the values are not correct but when I export the data frame and imported it back and did the same calculation it is giving the expected result. I am not able to understand why the function with same numbers are giving different result.

Can someone help me out and tell me why am I getting this wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Test2 <- read_excel("X/X/X/X/X/Test2.xlsx")
Test2 <- Test2 %>% 
  mutate(FACC1 = `Max (Act vs Cons)`/sum(`Max (Act vs Cons)`)) %>% 
  mutate(FACC2 = FACC1 * FCA)
```

Attached is the output after the calculation, this works perfectly in this data frame.

```
structure(list(Model = c("YX-530", "YX-530", "YX-530", "YX-530", 
"YX-530", "YX-530", "YX-530", "YX-530", "YX-530", "YX-530"), 
    X12 = c("X1-1278098", "X1-2582528", "X1-8286828", "X1-3177769", 
    "X1-6859533", "X1-2645991", "X1-9216675", "X1-4569652", "X1-6788335", 
    "X1-6508059"), FCA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 54.5454545454546, 33.3333333333333, 
    21.2121212121212, 0, 0, 0), `Max (Act vs Cons)` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2115.3, 534.12, 3261.72, 0, 0, 0), `Model Level Aggregation` = c(1377051.56, 
    1377051.56, 1377051.56, 1377051.56, 1377051.56, 1377051.56, 
    1377051.56, 1377051.56, 1377051.56, 1377051.56), `Final Forecast Accuracy` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0837946946590729, 0.0129277799881364, 0.0502385554829915, 
    0, 0, 0), FACC1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3.81536456078212e-05, 9.63391726565945e-06, 
    5.88316120417635e-05, 0, 0, 0), FACC2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00208110794224479, 
    0.000321130575521982, 0.00124794328573438, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But the same data frame with the same numbers are giving different output.

The code which I used for creating this data frame is:

```
X1 <- FAC_Template %>% 
  mutate(FACC1 = `Max (Act vs Cons)`/sum(`Max (Act vs Cons)`)) %>% 
  mutate(FACC2 = FACC1 * `Forecast Accuracy`)
```

The output which I got is in the below data frame.

```
structure(list(Model = c("3M-MA", "3M-MA", "3M-MA", "3M-MA", 
"3M-MA", "3M-MA", "3M-MA", "3M-MA", "3M-MA", "3M-MA"), `12NC's` = c("X01", 
"X02", "X03", "X04", "X05", 
"X06", "X07", "X08", "X09", 
"X10"), `Forecast Accuracy` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 54.55, 
33.33, 21.21, 0, 0, 0), `Max (Act vs Cons)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2115.3, 
534.12, 3261.72, 0, 0, 0), FACC1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00153610805974469, 
0.000387872186862778, 0.00236862590678885, 0, 0, 0), FACC2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0837946946590729, 0.0129277799881364, 0.0502385554829915, 
0, 0, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(Model = "3M-MA", 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

For Example I am taking the example:

**X05**, **FACC1**: **1.536108e-03** and **FACC2**: **0.083794695**.

But the same example from the other data frame is

**X1-6859533**, **FACC1**: **3.815365e-05** and **FACC2**: **2.081108e-03**.

This case **X1-6859533** is the correct number mathematically and I cant to resolve this, do anyone know what's wrong?. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Your second output is grouped by `Model`, which implies that your second data is too. Grouped data will make sum work differently -- summing across all observations for the first one, or only within each Model in the second one.

Comment: @JonSpring  So how do I go about it.  Is there a way to get it work in the normal way?

Comment: `FAC_Template %>% ungroup() %>% [the other lines]`

Comment: @JonSpring So you mean before I do this computation **mutate(FACC1 = Max (Act vs Cons)/ sum(Max (Act vs Cons))) %>% mutate(FACC2 = FACC1 * Forecast Accuracy)**. I have to use ungroup correct?

Comment: yes, that will remove grouping so that subsequent steps will work on the whole data instead of by group.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you so much, I was struggling for hours with this.. If you put this as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253609/discussion-between-user20203146-and-jon-spring).